# Error display while loading files

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to display an error while uploading a torrent file but i'm unsuccessful. Here is the problem code:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('torr', 'name', 'genre', 'cat', 'descr');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true){
            $errors[] = "<font color='#eeeeee'> Campurile marcate cu * sunt obligatorii.</font><br>";
            break 1;
        }
    }
}
```

etc

and here is my upload code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['torr']) === true){

    $allowed = array('torrent');
    $file_name = $_FILES['torr']['name'];
    $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.' ,$file_name)));
    $file_temp = $_FILES['torr']['tmp_name'];
    if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === false){
    $errors[] = "nu`i fisier torent";
    }else{
    $file_path = 'media/torr/' . $name . '-www.LegacyRo.info-' .substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
```

}

and instead of displaying an error when i try to upload another kind of file, i get this:

Notice: Undefined variable: file_path in x/y/z

I know that the query jumps out the file_path because the extension is not allowed, but i want it to be displayed as an error.

Any ideas?

here is the paste bin for a better understanding:
http://pastebin.com/z3vkRVUx

looks like all i had to do is move the extension check inside the errors area. All good now. Thanks for your replyes

Comment: in the future, please make an effort not to pile a bunch of code into 1 line.

Comment: i'm sorry about the 1 line but i couldn't manage to make it any other way. As you can see i managed with the second chunk but not with the first

Answer (score 0):

$file_name is defined $name mistakenly in your code.

```
try {
    move_uploaded_file
}
catch($err) {
    echo $err;

}
```

Comment: that is the final name wich must be added in the file name and it works. If i try to upload a .torrent file i have no problem. If i try to upload a different extension i can't manage to output the $errors[] = "error text here";